# Dynamic spell-checker for HTML text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-ui

I have a text box, created in HTML. The user may type input into this text box. I would like to validate their input dynamically, as they type, and search for spelling mistakes in their text. If there is a spelling mistake, underline the word.

This is a common functionality I assume, but I cannot find a plugin or API call that will accomplish this for me. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? Preferably something that will work in Spanish rather than English :).

Thanks you.

Comment: I guess this might help you. You can set the language,too. http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/.  Language files: http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JavaScript_SpellChecking_Dictionaries

Comment: read [link] https://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/

Comment: spelling mistakes can uderline browser / OS by default

Answer (score 1):

There are tree options for spellchecking :

1. Using a [jQuery plugin](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/10/free-jquery-spell-checker-plugins.html.html)
2. Using the build-in spell checker of your browser with the [`spellcheck`attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_spellcheck.asp)
3. Using a spell checker in a [WYSIWYG editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_spellcheck)